# Open hidden div as a "popup" next to the hyperlink clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Assume the following simple HTML:

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<href="#" id="doExport">Export Now</a>
<div id="exportPopup">
<p>From: <input type="text" id="dateFrom" /></p>
<p>To: <input type="text" id="dateTo" /></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now also assume that there is CSS that styles #exportPopup appropriiately and sets it to display:none initially. This brings me to two questions:

1. How do I make that hidden DIV (#exportPopup) show up right where the #doExport link is clicked?
2. How do I use the JQuery datepicker on those two input boxes?

For Question 2 I have already tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $("#dateFrom").datepicker();
  $("#dateTo").datepicker();    
});
```

and it just doesn't work when I click those boxes. I hope someone can enlighten me.

Comment: Could you throw it in a fiddle for us so we can play around with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a rough model at http://jsfiddle.net/santoshjoshi/32enE/1/

so basically used the `jQuery dialog plugin` you need to add following code open the dialog box

**HTML Code**

```
<a href="#" id="doExport">Export Now</a>
<div id="exportPopup" style='display:none'>
   <p>From: <input type="text" id="dateFrom" /></p>
   <p>To: <input type="text" id="dateTo" /></p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#dateFrom").datepicker();
    $("#dateTo").datepicker();   
 });

$( "#doExport" ).click(function() {
   $( "#exportPopup" ).dialog( );
});
```

also  please have a look at jQuery dialog documentation to customize your popup/dialog
http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

**'UPDATE'**
  used following resources

- http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js
- http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css ' Theme is smoothness'

Comment: You say you "added the Jquery dialog plugin" -- I thought that was part of JQuery UI? If not, how do I get to it? Also, your datepicker looks much nicer than mine. What theme is it from? If not from a theme, how did you get it to look that way?

Comment: yep, `jQuery Dialog` is part of `jQuery UI`, Just check the fiddle source code. I have only added `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'  and `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js` . Also updated the answer for css an js changes